# swapping every two chars in the string with Python

Tags: python, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the simplest way to swap char in a string with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605439/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-swap-char-in-a-string-with-python)

Original string :
'badcfe'

after swapping:

'abcdef'