# Modify a string by swapping multiple letters

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I have a very long string like `'ABCEEEEEEDEDAAA......'` but it is only made up of five letters. Say I want all `'A'` to be `'D'` and vice versa, and same to `'B'` and `'C'`(an example would be nucleotides in DNA....). The example, after modification, would be `'DCBEEEEEEAEADDD......`. I realized that code like `string.replace('A','D').replace('D','A')` just wouldn't work. And I would like to know what is the fastest approach since the other approach that comes up to me is just finding every index, which looks a little bit complicated.

Comment: string is immutable in python.

Comment: Use a temp character. For example: `s.replace('A', '!')`, then `s.replace('B', 'A')`, and `s.replace('!', 'B')`.. I'm not sure what values you want to swap, but this should do the trick.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the simplest way to swap char in a string with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605439/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-swap-char-in-a-string-with-python)

Comment: @MarounMaroun : that would be  fine if only two chars need to be swapped. But since here many chars need to be replaced, that method won't be the optimum.

Comment: He can do the swap of each letter one by one, there shouldn't be any conflict..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the requirement is for ***multiple replacements***, its better to use [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) by creating a mapping table first using [`str.maketranslate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans).

Example using a shortened version of your sample where `'A'->'D'` , `'D'->'A'` , `'B'->'C'` , `'C'->'B'`

```
>>> s = 'ABCEEEEEEDEDAAA'
>>> orig = 'ABCD'
>>> rep = 'DCBA'
>>> trans_table = str.maketrans(orig,rep)

>>> s.translate(trans_table)
=> 'DCBEEEEEEAEADDD'
```

---

Another method would be to make use of `str.replace` function, but which would require more amount of code lines for the same functionality. It can be done by using a *temporary placeholder for replacements*.

Example : suppose for just `'A'->'B'` and `'B'->'A'`

```
>>> s = 'ABBA'
>>> s = s.replace('A','$')
#'$BB$'
>>> s = s.replace('B','A')
#'$AA$'
>>> s = s.replace('$','B')
>>> s
=> 'BAAB'
```

Here `$` is used as placeholder. As you can see, this becomes tiresome with large replacement requirements.

***NOTE :*** in the above method, the placeholders should be unique too and should not be already present in the string.