# Python - how to extract text from list

Tags: python, python-3.6

My question is:

```
Extract: "agne"
From:    "Orange"
```

I am trying to extract not `ange` but `agne` from `Orange`. How do I change `n` and `g`f?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the simplest way to swap char in a string with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605439/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-swap-char-in-a-string-with-python)

Comment: Since you did not explain what you are doing, I'd say this is simplest: `def extract(whatever): return "agne"`. It does exactly what you requested.

Comment: You should be more specific. For example, do you need to delete the first  two characters from a string, or you want to keep the last four?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to extract text from a list:

```
>>> fruit = 'Orange'
>>> print (fruit[2] + fruit[4] + fruit[3] + fruit[5])
agne
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the characters of `extract` and if the character is in `word` , `append` to a `list` then `.join()` the `list` into a `str`

Using *list comprehension* :

```
word = 'Orange'
extract = 'agne'
print(''.join([i for i in [*extract] if i in word]))
```

> ```
> agne
> ```

Expanded loop:

```
new = []
for i in extract:
    if i in list(word):
        new.append(i)

new = ''.join(new)
print(new)
```