# how do I swap around characters from a given string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def swap_adj(string):
    if len(string) % 2 == 1: 
        string = string[:-1]
    else:
        string = string
        for i in range (0, len(string), 2): print(string[i]+string[i+1], end= " ")
```

I want the program to swap around each pair of 2 characters so if I inputted (abcdef) as the argument, then it would output (badcfe). Can't seem to figure out the problem.

Comment: Here's a hint: string slicing can go backwards by making the 3rd argument negative.

Comment: If you want to swap around the characters, you should be printing `string[i+1] + string[i]` not the other way around.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605439/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-swap-each-pair-of-adjoining-chars-in-a-string-with-p

Answer (score 0):

Your original code does not swap characters because you print them in order. You need to put the `i+1`th character before the `i`th character in order for you to achieve the desired effect. Furthermore, your code doesn't output anything for odd-length strings because of how your `if-else` statement is structured. The following is an improved version of your code:

```
def swap_adj(string):
    if len(string) % 2 == 1: 
        string = string[:-1]
    for i in range (0, len(string), 2):
        print(string[i+1]+string[i], end='')
        
swap_adj("abcdef")
```

A more concise version of your code however is the following:

```
def swap_adj(string):
    return "".join([j + i for i, j in zip(string[::2], string[1::2])])

print(swap_adj("abcdef"))
```